# bootbox.confirm dose not display the message and page crashed

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootbox

I'm new to bootstrap.I'm trying to show confirm message with bootbox format after click on delete btn .I know that bootbox.confirm need callback function so I utilize result and checked if its true then show it.I expect to see this: Are you sure to delete this customer?  but after click noting happen and browser just freeze and I have to refresh it again. 
this is all my code:

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("ADD New Customer", "CreatNewCustomer", "Customer", new { @class = "form-control" })
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p> there is no customer</p>

}
else
{ 
    <table id="Customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Customers</th>

                <th>Discount Rate</th>
                <th>Delete </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Customer in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                @*<td>@Customer.Name</td>*@
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(Customer.Name.ToString(),"Edit","Customer",new {id=Customer.CustomerID },null)</td>
                <td>@Customer.MembershipType.MembershipName</td>
                <td>
                    <button data-customer-id="@Customer.CustomerID" class="btn-link js-delete"> Delete</button>
                </td>

            </tr>




        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
@section scripts

    {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    var butten = $(this)
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/customer/" + butten.attr("data-customer-id"),
                        method: "Delete",
                        success: function () {
                            console.log("success"),
                                butten.parents("tr").remove();

                        }


                    })
                }
            })


    })
    })
</script>
    }
```

Main part is here:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
var butten = $(this);
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customer/" + butten.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "Delete",
                            success: function () {
                                console.log("success"),
                                    butten.parents("tr").remove();

                            }


                        })
                    }
                })


        })
        })
    </script>
```

I can't get what's wrong with that.
When I use bootbox.confirm my code not works but when I use confirm alon like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
var butten = $(this);
                confirm("Are you sure to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customer/" + butten.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "Delete",
                            success: function () {
                                console.log("success"),
                                    butten.parents("tr").remove();

                            }


                        })
                    }
                })
    })

        })
    </script>
```

my code works. I have installed bootbox version 4.3.0 and set in my bundle config like this :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

And I use vs 2017
Hope someone help me.

Comment: Is your ajax call returning a 200 OK response. If not your current code does not do anything. Check your browser console/network tab

Comment: The context of `var butten = $(this)` is not what you think. If you're trying to store a reference to the button, you need to do that outside of the call to bootbox.confirm

Comment: Dear @TiesonT. I did as you say. you are right about  storing outside of bootbox.confirm but still noting changed and  I have my problem yet...

Comment: dear @Shyju there is noting in network, xhr tab. so my current code does not do anything , I know this, my problem is that : Why this code not works ?

Comment: @shyju and I have edited my question.

Comment: @TiesonT. and I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a reference to the button that triggered the click event, you (still) are selecting the wrong item when doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var butten = $(this);
```

Where you have that line in your latest edit, you're selecting the document. What you need is:

```
$("#Customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {

    // THIS is where you select the button...
    var butten = $(this);

    // ... the rest of your code
}
```

If you're struggling with this, I suggest spending some time on the jQuery Learning Center: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Dear @TiesonT.  you are right about putting   var butten = $(this);  after this part : $("#Customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {} but still I have problem with bootbox.confirm its not work. bu without boobox its work.

Comment: @AliEshghi If you haven't read it already, I'd note the documentation, specifically: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#known-limitations - Bootbox is (mostly) just a helper for Bootstrap modals, and (because they're just markup) Bootstrap modals can't block the UI thread like a native confirm dialog. That means you need to prevent the default action of your delete button, or explicitly set the type of the button to "button", since the default type is "submit".